# how to create a list of values from one key-value pair based on the value of another k-v pair from a list of dictionaries with two key-value pairs

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate through a list of dictionaries with the goal of producing a list of lists of values from one k,v pair based on the value of the other k,v pair. Each dictionary contains two k,v pairs, the respective keys of which are the same.

For example, given this list:

```
dict_list =[{'basket': 1, 'fruit': 'apple'},
            {'basket': 1, 'fruit': 'orange'},
            {'basket': 1, 'fruit': 'peach'},
            {'basket': 2, 'fruit': 'kiwi'},
            {'basket': 2, 'fruit': 'lemon'},
            {'basket': 3, 'fruit': 'grape'}]
```

I would like to produce this list:

```
list_list = [['apple','orange','peach'],
             ['kiwi','lemon'],
             ['grape']]
```

I am having difficulty working through the iteration to achieve segregated lists. So far, I have only been able to get a list of all the fruit values together. Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use groupby from itertools.

```
import itertools

list_list = [[f['fruit'] for f in v] for k, v in itertools.groupby(dict_list, key=lambda x: x['basket'])]
```

This assumes that the basket entries in `dict_list` are sorted (or same baskets are next to each other in the list). If that's not the case, just sort before `groupby`.

Comment: wow, this seems like a really sleek solution. I think sorting would be necessary. Something like: dlist = sorted(dlist, key = lambda i: i['basket'])?  thank you

Comment: @Gcm yes, that'll do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way without using `groupby`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict_list = [
    {'basket': 1, 'fruit': 'apple'},
    {'basket': 1, 'fruit': 'orange'},
    {'basket': 1, 'fruit': 'peach'},
    {'basket': 2, 'fruit': 'kiwi'},
    {'basket': 2, 'fruit': 'lemon'},
    {'basket': 3, 'fruit': 'grape'},
]


def to_list(dlist):
    full_d = defaultdict(list)
    for d in dlist:
        basket = d['basket']
        fruit = d['fruit']
        full_d[basket].append(fruit)
    return list(full_d.values())


print(to_list(dict_list))
```

The output:

```
[['apple', 'orange', 'peach'], ['kiwi', 'lemon'], ['grape']]
```

Or simplifying a little more:

```
def to_list(dlist):
    full_d = defaultdict(list)
    for d in dlist:
        full_d[d['basket']].append(d['fruit'])
    return list(full_d.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't exactly what you asked, but maybe you should reconsider the way you're structuring things. Consider maybe having a class that can maintain the state of your baskets and return their values like so:

```
class Basket:
    def __init__(self):
        self.basket = []

    def add_item(self, item):
        self.basket.append(item)

    def get_basket_items(self):
        return self.basket
```

This is how you could implement the above class into your workflow:

```
baskets = {}
baskets.update({1: Basket()})
baskets.update({2: Basket()})
baskets[1].add_item("orange")
baskets[1].add_item("apple")
baskets[2].add_item("kiwi")

all_items =[]
for basket in baskets.values():
    all_items.append(basket.get_basket_items())

print(all_items)
```

Classes are really useful when you want to start doing some funky things with the elements in your data structures. They are a little more flexible in that regard.
Hope that helps!

Comment: well explained. I'll spend some time with this. thank you.